# Cannot find parent template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template called `reg_form.html` in an application `reg_manual`. which looks similar to:

```
{% extends "registration/base.html" %}


{% block content %}
Some content

{% endblock %}
```

The `base.html` template has the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
            <div class="content">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both templates are in the folder `reg_manual/templates/registration/`.

Now if run the following in a Django shell: (This error occurs also calling the URL from browser.)

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
render_to_string('registration/reg_form.html')
```

I get `TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html` error.

If I run `render_to_string('registration/base.html')`, the template is found and rendered. Also if I run the application on Windows with same settings.

This error occurs only on the production server (Ubuntu). Also changing the ownership of `templates` folder to `www-data` did not help.

Do somebody know a solution?

Comment: What is the value of `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your settings.py?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings`

`settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS` 
Out[2]: `()`

and for:  `settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS`

Out[3]:
    `('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')`

Comment: Ok, this may be obvious but did you register `reg_manual` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes, it is registered too.